# List files/folders in google drive including sub folders and so on... with google drive api

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a google drive folder that has so many folders, then these folders also have other folders/files inside them and so on... I am using this code to list all the folders/files in the parent folder and I am putting the files/folders in a data frame like this:

```
import pickle
import os.path
import io
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from numpy import cumproduct
import pandas as pd
import gdown
from pyasn1.type.constraint import ContainedSubtypeConstraint
import requests
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
import httplib2

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'test.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

folder_id='valid folder id'
query=f"parents = '{folder_id}'"

response=service.files().list(pageSize=1000, q=query).execute()
files=response.get('files')
nextPageToken=response.get('nextPageToken')

while nextPageToken:
    response=service.files().list(pageSize=1000, pageToken=nextPageToken, q=query).execute()
    files.extend(response.get('files'))
    nextPageToken=response.get('nextPageToken')

df = pd.DataFrame(files)
print(df)
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
          kind            id               name                        mimeType
0        drive#file    valid id          Testfolder           application/vnd.google-apps.folder
.           .             .                   .                            .
.           .             .                   .                            .
.           .             .                   .                            .
2000   drive#file    valid id          Testfolder2000         application/vnd.google-apps.folder
```

How can I modify this code to also list all the files in sub folders?
Lets say that the parent folder name is root and I have files in this path: `root/folder1/folder2/folder.../test.png`. So, the output I want is to have all the files/folders in a dataframe.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111744/listing-all-google-drive-files-and-folders-in-python-and-save-ids/66121937#66121937) work for you?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes i did, i will post an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(file.json, SCOPES)
resource = {
    #"oauth2": creds,
    "service_account": creds,
    "id": "{0}".format(folderId),
    "fields": "files(name,id)",
}

res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
df = pd.json_normalize(res['fileList'], record_path=['files'])
```